# Awesome WM: Change Tag Label Color for Notifications?

Tags: awesome

I'm using the default awesome theme. One thing I really like is how notifications are handled for pidgin - when a new message comes in the tag label (in the upper left of the screen, on the top bar) turns red.

Is there a way I could make Icedove have the same kind of notifications? I would especially like the tag label to turn red when a new unread message arrives in the inbox. Right now I set my Icedove preferences to "show an alert", but this only generates a notification box in the lower right of the screen.

Update: Installing the "New Mail Attention" add-on for Thunderbird adds the red color notifications!

Comment: I doubt it, since this seems to be a general Awesome mechanism reacting to a "hey, this window has an exciting update that you should see" flag which is raised by completely application-specific logic.

Comment: I see that in pidgin I have the "Set window manager Urgent hint" option selected in my "Message Notification" plug-in. Perhaps there's a way to tell Icedove's notifications to be "Urgent"?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to enable `red` notification color on a tag where pidgin is located. As @bubblesinsideme mentioned. Ensure that you have option `Set window manager "URGENT" hint` enabled in `Configure Plugin` window (`Tools > Plugins`).